# How do I snap multiple objects, based on a vertex from one of these objects, to a vertex of another object?

Tags: objects

As per title.

I have essentially half of my work that needs to be moved, and I want to move it sharply, snapping as it was snapped before to the other object.
I had to reduce the height of the floor of a building, and I need to bring down all the rest of the building.
I could of course just "put it there, more or less", but as I'm here and I want to learn Blender for good, I prefer to wait and ask.
I've spent now almost one hour between attempts, moving the cursor, selecting a vertex in edit object mode, etc. and watching tutorials.
I even tried to move the origin point of the object that must be reference for the group of objects to move, to the protagonist vertex. Doesn't work even like this.
A realy mistery.

Answer (score 3):

Snapping is a bit hard to control sometimes, but you could create an empty on the vertex location, parent all your objects to this empty, and move the empty until it snaps to the destination vertex:

[image]

Comment: Mh I thought about this but I wanted to avoid it. We are talking about tens and tens of objects inside a small building... to parent and deparent... I'll see if it's viable, as apparently there's no other way. However this should be a feature to add quickly, as I think many request something similar. Snap is cool in Blender, but something in the interface simply doesn't work when the situation is complex, like in this case, where Blender thinks that a far lamp is the vertex I want to snap... I mean: I **last select** the mesh that I want to snap... use that at least...

Comment: Yes the snap tool would need to be improved, but actually my trick is even simpler than what I said, you just need to parent to the empty and then snap the empty to the vertex  ;)

Comment: Yes I did it, I also thought about this solution, but wanted to avoid it. In fact, after snapping, I deparented the objects, and ALL of them lost the hierarchy. Well, lesson learned I guess.